# Ubuntu 14.04 wifi not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on windows 8 , and having problem connecting to my internet router, i have D-link N150 wireless router which is working fine with my windows and other devices , also on ubuntu while i am connecting my mobile device as hot spot its working great there but while connecting to my router it fails or even after trying to 10 20 times it connects and disconnect in minute.

**Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2**

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
```

i am new to ubuntu not having much knowledge of it so any help is appreciated .

Comment: On which channel is the router transmitting? Try to make it transmit on channel at most 11.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 added the output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2"

Comment: the same driver is working great with windows , also as i have mentioned when i connect my mobile's hot spot with ubuntu it works good and i didn't face any problem in connecting ....

Comment: Try changing the security on your router.

Comment: it is wpa-psk/wpa2-psk aes currently

Comment: I no it's not ideal but try changing to WEP and see will it connect then.

Comment: trued changing from wpa-psk/wpa2-psk aes to WEP , then wpa2-psk but it doesn't make any difference , the problem still persist

Comment: @William i tried again changing from wpa2-psk to wep this time its connected but after some time its again disconnected, changing from wpa2-psk to wep make any diff ?

Comment: @Pilot6, any thing from your side ? do i need to update/install the driver or is there any problem with my router configuration ?

Comment: I can't help with this adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and download this file:

```
wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11876059/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz
```

Now extract the file:

```
tar -xvf DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz
```

Enter the directory:

```
cd ~/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
```

Now make and install the file:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Last step is to activate the driver

```
sudo modprobe rt3290sta
```

A reboot may be required after install is complete.

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/Wireless’: File exists

Comment: install: cannot stat ‘rt3290sta.ko’: No such file or directory

Comment: I can't understand how you got this? Where did you extract the file to?

Comment: installation failed with these two errors

Comment: under home/tushar/

Comment: Extract to desktop and then cd to Desktop and then to the file and try install again.

Comment: still its giving me the same error while running make and instal

Comment: You could try this command : sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
Then try the install again. It's beyond my skill on this card to no any more knowledge.

Comment: after installing this , should i change my router setting to wpa2-psk again ?

Comment: If it works then you could try it.

Comment: its not working ,,,,,i have tried make and install after sudo update and build-essential linux-header but still get the same error ...any thing else i should try ?